# Traduction de "(But) which is which?"

Tags: traduction, anglais, interrogative

> Suppose we need the formula for the area of a circle for some computation. Like many people who learned geometry too long ago to recall with any certainty, two expressions may pop into our mind when we think of circles:  πr^2  and  2πr . One expression is the circumference of a circle of radius r and the other is its area. **But which is which**?

Je me demande comment dire en français **But which is which** ou comment rendre en français une idée voisine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On peut utiliser la même structure en français : « *Which is which?* » correspond à « Lequel est lequel ? » pour un nom masculin, ou « Laquelle est laquelle ? » pour un nom féminin. Ici il s'agit de *formules* (on n'utilise pas « expression » dans ce sens en français), nom féminin, donc : « Mais laquelle est laquelle ? »

Answer (score 2):

J'ai également beaucoup de mal avec le calque "Lequel est lequel ?" qui me semble relativement inusité. L'expression anglaise est assez idiomatique et sa traduction littérale en français n'acquerra un sens identique qu'avec beaucoup d'usage, ce qui ne s'est pas encore vraiment produit.

Un pendant commun à "which is which" est "**qu'est-ce qui correspond à quoi**", qu'on pourrait modifier dans le cas présent en "Mais quelle formule correspond à quoi ?"

Comment: "Lequel est lequel ?" est artificiel, mais l'original n'est pas pour autant idiomatique.

Answer (score 0):

On ne dit certainement pas « laquelle est laquelle ? ». ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Lequel+est+lequel+%3F%2CLaquelle+est+laquelle+%3F&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=))

Ce que l'on peut dire

- Mais laquelle convient ?
- Mais laquelle des deux convient ?
- Mais de laquelle s'agit-il ?
- Mais quelle est celle qui convient ?
- Mais quelle est la bonne ?
- Mais laquelle est la bonne ?
- Mais c'est laquelle ?

Comment: @dimitris La traduction littérale est parfaitement correcte et courante. La plupart des phrases proposées dans cette réponse sont correctes, mais ne conviennent pas dans ce contexte parce qu'elles n'ont pas le sens voulu.

Comment: @dimitris Désolé, cela me semblait impossible à dire, tellement impossible que je ne l'ai même pas vérifié par un ngram ; encore une fois, désolé !

Comment: @dimitris Cependant je viens de trouver par ngram que ce n'est pas du tout dans le [texte imprimé](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=laquelle+est+laquelle+%3F&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=)

Comment: @dimitris vérification supplémentaire : on trouve la combinaison mais depuis très récemment **et** sans le point d'interrogation.[ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=laquelle+est+laquelle&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Claquelle%20est%20laquelle%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Claquelle%20est%20laquelle%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Je ne comprends pas du tout les votes négatives. Y a-t-il une explication possible ? La réponse de @Eau qui dort est d'accord avec la tienne concernant le calque "lequel est lequel".

Comment: @dimitris En effet, le commentaire de Eau qui dort  correspond beaucoup à l'impression que j'avais…mais peut être que comme moi il n'aurait pas été exposé suffisamment à l'usage reconnu ; (les votes négati**fs**) ; Explication au vote ? Très probablement en référence au et/ou en accord avec le commentaire de Gilles qui dit que les phrases ne conviennent pas dans le présent contexte ! Ils ne conçoivent pas que l'on puisse déplacer le contexte et parler de la formule qui convient à la surface au lieu de quelle formule convient à quelle caractéristique. Ça peut être important de ne pas diverger.

Comment: Donc l'on a trois locuteurs natifs du français parmi lesquels deux partagent la même idée pour "lequel est lequel" lequel ils considèrent comme inusité. Ça n'explique les votes négatifs:-)!

Comment: @dimitris Je crois que le droit d'être sévère est entièrement acquis à tout citoyen !

Comment: @dimitris Il y a une grosse différence entre Eau qui dort exprime une opinion respectable (*j'ai du mal*) et dont la qualité de francophone ne fait aucun doute et LPH qui assène une affirmation sans appel et fausse (*on ne dit certainement pas*), et dont je ne crois pas une seconde à la qualité de "francophone natif". Pour ce qui concerne *lequel est lequel*, j'ai déjà utilisé cette expression, je l'ai déjà entendue, on en trouve de nombreux exemples sur Internet, elle ne me pose aucun problème. D'où mon *downvote* ici.